# Throwing an Exception from OnClickListener

Tags: java, android

I'm kind of new to java, what I'm trying to do here is sending a Post request everytime a button is pressed. Here's my code

```
   public class Remotetask extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView tv;
    Button btn;

    public void PostRequest(String url_from_text) throws IOException {
        String url = url_from_text;
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();
        //print in String
        tv.setText(response.toString());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_eve_aioremote);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button1);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) throws IOException{
                PostRequest("api endpoint");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This line here though

> public void onClick(View v) throws IOException

Gives me this error here:

*error: onClick(View) in  cannot implement onClick(View) in OnClickListener
overridden method does not throw IOException*

I found another post of a guy asking a similar question but the answers really didn't help me out as I'm kind of new to this. Thank you.

Comment: throw a runtimeexeption not a checked exception or handle the exception  directly in the onCick method

Comment: i suggest you use volley or retrofit library instead of  manual code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove that IOException throw from your onclick. Like this

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
  try {
    PostRequest("api endpoint");
   } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The original method of onClickListener doesn't throw any Exception that's why it is giving error.

Comment: That's the first thing I tried, but if I do that I get  "error: unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown" for the line "PostRequest("api endpoint");". Thank you so much for the quick reply though.

Comment: Okay got it! Thank you for the quick solution!

Answer (score 1):

**throws IOException** Please dont throw this in Onclick because you already throw the exception in PostRequest Method

**Try this:**

```
 btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        PostRequest("api endpoint");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

implement try-catch instead of throwing IOException ,

```
 public class Remotetask extends AppCompatActivity {

 TextView tv;
 Button btn;

 public void PostRequest(String url_from_text) {
 try{
String url = url_from_text;
URL obj = new URL(url);
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
con.setRequestMethod("GET");
con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;
StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    response.append(inputLine);
}
in.close();
//print in String
tv.setText(response.toString());
}catch(Exception e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
}
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_eve_aioremote);
btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button1);
tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        PostRequest("api endpoint");
    }
});
```

}

Answer (score 1):

handle error like this

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    try {
        PostRequest("api endpoint");
    } catch (Exception e)‏ {
        //error handling code
    }

}
});
```

Comment: Yup! Got it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code Snippet please remove throw `IOException` from `OnClick`

```
  public class Remotetask extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView tv;
    Button btn;

    public void PostRequest(String url_from_text) throws IOException {
        String url = url_from_text;
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();
        //print in String
        tv.setText(response.toString());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_eve_aioremote);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button1);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try{
                PostRequest("api endpoint");
                } catch (Exception e)
                  {
                   e.getStackTrace();
                  }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Hope this may help you